# Connect Smart TV to laptop

Tags: smart-tv

I am working with not a well known Smart TV manufacturer, It uses Android 4.0. I want to customize its dashboard and splash animation played during the system loads. Working on my own launcher and dashboard alongside, but now when I have hit a roadblock when the testing phase has arrived. I cannot use a smart tv emulator for this purpose as the manufacturer is not either of Samsung, LG or Google.

I want to be able to test it on the Smart TV itself, but I cannot connect to the device through my laptop. Wi-Fi, LAN or usb cable connection, tried all, but I cannot access the system itself as an emulator on my AVD manager... Any ideas where to proceed from here?

Comment: I think you can do it from a Linux terminal if you know the Vendor ID and device ID. There is a 51-rules file you might have to modify though. Not sure though.

Comment: I have the MAC address of the device..will it work?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_debug

Comment: $ /<SDKpath>/platform-tools/adb connect <IPAddress> try with the IP of your Device.

Comment: @AstralProjection Thank you for the help, I am currently on step `4` of the link provided. I cannot navigate the option `In the Settings application, select Applications Development.` in the device. The system uses android 4.0.4.

Comment: Once you are on the Settings page choose Applications and then development?